# Can help text/placeholders be added to component attributes in the Lightning App Builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have one attribute that is exposed in the Lightning App Builder.

[image]

It is an attribute in my component specified as:

```
<aura:attribute name="stepObjectFields" type="String" default="" access="GLOBAL" description="A list of objects and fields, using special formatting to indicate different uses for the item in the list" />
```

And exposed int he Lightning App Builder using the lightning component design file:

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="stepObjectFields" label="Step Object Fields" />
</design:component>
```

However, this input field has a couple special notations users have to use in order to make the component work like they want.

Is it possible to add any sort of help text, or placeholder text in the Lightning App Builder for this attribute to give users information on how to properly fill out the field?

Comment: Your question would have been hugely improved by mentioning you are working with a *design file* and including some sample markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the placeholder with the ***placeholder*** attribute in design file .

```
<design:component label="Hello World">
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" placeholder="Hello"/>
</design:component>
```

Refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation! My Googling did not get me there :(. But the description and placeholder are just what I need.